etcd transaction Commit() returned "Succeeded: false", but value was stored?
I have an issue with etcd transaction, I have following piece of code:
for attempt := 1; ; attempt++ {
    resp, err := kv.Tnx(ctx).
    If(clientv3util.KeyMissing(key)).
    Then(clientv3.OpPut(key, string(value))).
    Else(clientv3.OpGet(key)).
    Commit()

    if err != nil && attempt < 3 {
        log.Log(ctx, err)
        continue
    } else if err != nil && attempt >= 3 {
        return err
    }
    if !resp.Succeeded {
        return errors.New(" Unsuccessfull txn")
    }
}

The problem is when I first "attempt" do this request and got and err == "etcdserver:+request+timed+out", then for loop starts all over again, and this time I got response from a transaction "Succeeded: false" and I return an error to the client as well. However data was actually added to the etcd database... Why is that, I got an error first time, but actually data was added isn't it the place for rolling back or what?
